# All CiviMail users can see every mailing in 'Include Mailing', even ones they shouldn't have access to

Tags: civimail, permissions, acl

My expectation was that a user without Administrate CiviCRM permission would not be able to see another user's mailings in the Recipients: Include Mailing list.

Instead a user with access over **List A** can select a previous mailing that went to **List B** that they don't have permissions over. Would that mailing deliver? Is that not a loophole in the ACL?

Happy to be corrected if I'm missing an easy setting.

Comment: This refers to 'mailings' but I wonder if it should be saying 'Mailing List/Group'

Comment: Hi, are you saying my question should refer to 'Mailing List/Group' or the CiviCRM UI should be clearer?

Comment: Your question. sorry i wasn't clear. You say "see another user's mailings" which I initially read as worded - but later realised this was to do with seeing Groups, not mailings (also in title)